# pytest working on directory of tests reading avro but not on whole test folder

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, pytest, avro

I have a whole directory called *test* that serves as a directory for the tests of my project. Inside of that I have several subdirectories where each of them contains some test files. One of these subdirectories is also a directory called *it* (*it* stands for integration tests) which serves as a directory for end-to-end tests of my application. The application is a pyspark app that alongside other logic it also reads *avro* files.

For testing I use `pytest`. When I run `pytest` on the whole *test* directory, all the unit tests pass but the end-to-end tests that read from avro fail with an exception

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: avro. Avro is built-in but external data source module since Spark 2.4. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Apache Avro Data Source Guide"
```

Once I run `pytest` only on the *it* directory which contains just the end-to-end tests, all of them pass without any problems.

What I also tried is that I moved some file with unit tests to the *it* directory. When I run `pytest` on the *it* directory when it also contains a file with unit tests, the end-to-end tests fail again and the unit tests work.

`pytest` seems to have the avro library included out-of-the-box as it works on the end-to-end test files without any additional parameters linking the avro library.

Any ideas on what configuration or whatever may I be missing?

Comment: A workaround that I just found is to run `pytest` with `--ignore=path_to_it` to run all the tests except of the ones in the *it* directory and then run `pytest` with the path to the *it* dir as an argument. But I still do not feel satisfied with this one.